# How to concatenate route strings from [Route] and CRUD operation headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I would like to concatenate the route specified in my `[Route()]` header with the routes in my `[HttpPost()]`, `[HttpGet()]`, `[HttpPut()]` and `[HttpDelete()]` headers.

I tried researching.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AdminController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/user/add/{num1}/")]
    public IActionResult SumActionResult(int num1)
    {
        return Ok(num1 );
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call the `SumActionResult` method by using the following uri: `

```
localhost/api/admin/user/add/input
```

Comment: The correct path would be `localhost/api/admin/user/add/input`. where input is `int` expected by your API.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the /api/ in the original post. Either way, I can only access the method using localhost/user/add/input.

Comment: *I can only access the method* - You can access the way intent or you want to access  as `localhost/user/add/input`. If later, then remove the `api` string from `Route` attribute.

Comment: dude, with the code declared as is, i can still only access that method using `localhost/user/add/input`. My api string in the route attribute doesn't get concatenated to the api strings in the crud attributes

Comment: @NAlexP remove the first slash from the action route template. it is overriding the route template on the controller

Comment: awesome, @Nkosi, that's exactly what i needed <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you shoud replace `[HttpGet("/user/add/{num1}/")]` with `[HttpGet("user/add/{num1}")]`